# How do I get data from float[], JSONArray parsing?

Tags: java, arrays

I get a response in the JSONArray form which looks like this:

```
"["37:0.00",
"60:23.50:55.00:22.22:52.00:192.55:20.00"
"61:0.00"]";
```

In these 3 rows the first numbers (37, 60, 61) are IDs (type `int`). 
The other numbers for these specific rows are values (type `float`).
How do I get these values for a specific ID to `float[]`?

Here's my code:

```
public void setValuesFromResponse(String response) {
    deviceList = database.getDevices();
    List<float[]> parsedData = parse(response);
    Log.i("setValFromResp: ", "parsedData --> DONE");

    for (int i = 0; i < parsedData.size(); i++) {
        int parsedDeviceId = (int) parsedData.get(i)[0]; //get ID
        float[] values =    parsedData.get(i)[1];
      //how to check if there is another value in another index (for this exmaple index 2
    }
}
```

Here is the parse method:

```
public List<float[]> parse(String json) 
{ 
    List<float[]> list = new ArrayList<>(); 
    try { 
        JSONArray array = new JSONArray(json); 
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) { 
            String dataByDevice = array.getString(i); 
            String[] values = dataByDevice.split(":"); 
            list.add(new float[values.length]); 
            for (int j = 0; j < values.length; j++) { 
                list.get(i)[j] = Float.parseFloat(values[j]); 
            }
        } 
        return list;
     }
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is in your `parse()` method?

Comment: <code>
public List<float[]> parse(String json) {
        List<float[]> list = new ArrayList<>();

        try {
            JSONArray array = new JSONArray(json);
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                String dataByDevice = array.getString(i);
                String[] values = dataByDevice.split(":");
                list.add(new float[values.length]);
                for (int j = 0; j < values.length; j++) {
                    list.get(i)[j] = Float.parseFloat(values[j]);
                }
            }
            return list;
        }
    }
<code>

Comment: you should figure out how to get the id's along with the values when you parse the JSON then you can put id,value in a hashmap or something...

Comment: it is even possible to get data from float[] the way i wanted?

Comment: what do you mean to get the id and value from a json object? I think it is probably possible...I'm not sure what you are asking?

Comment: no, array parseData is list od float[] objects, so to get data from this array. maybe i did misunderstanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"//how to check if there is another value in another index (for this exmaple index 2" you can add another inner loop to iterate over the array.

```
for (int i = 0; i < parsedData.size(); i++) {
    int parsedDeviceId = (int) parsedData.get(i)[0]; //get ID
    float[] values =    parsedData.get(i)[1];
  //how to check if there is another value in another index (for this exmaple index 2
}
```

Like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < parsedData.size(); i++) {
    int parsedDeviceId = (int) parsedData.get(i)[0]; //get ID
    for(int j = 1; j < parsedData.get(i).length; j++)
    {
         //process parsedData.get(i)[j] here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have all data including `id` in one array, you can simply skip `id` to get values.

```
public List<float[]> parse(String json) {
    List<float[]> list = new ArrayList<>();
    JSONArray array = new JSONArray(json);
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
        String dataByDevice = array.getString(i);
        String[] values = dataByDevice.split(":");
        list.add(new float[values.length]);
        for (int j = 0; j < values.length; j++) {
             list.get(i)[j] = Float.parseFloat(values[j]);
        }
    }
    return list;
}

public void setValuesFromResponse(String response) {
    List<float[]> parsedData = parse(response);

    for(int i = 0; i < parsedData.size(); ++i) {
        int parsedDeviceId = (int) parsedData.get(i)[0]; // get ID
        System.out.print(parsedDeviceId + " : ");
        for(int j = 0; j < parsedData.get(i).length; ++j) {
            System.out.print(parsedData.get(i)[j] + ", ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

or you can create a copy of array and then iterate through it

```
for(int i = 0; i < parsedData.size(); ++i) {
    int parsedDeviceId = (int) parsedData.get(i)[0]; // get ID
    float[] data = Arrays.copyOfRange(parsedData.get(i), 1, parsedData.get(i).length);
    System.out.print(parsedDeviceId + " : ");
    for(int j = 0; j < data.length; ++j) {
        System.out.print(data[j] + ", ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Also, this is example of how to use `Map`, I think this is more appropriate in your situation.

```
public Map<Integer, float[]> parse(String json) {
    Map<Integer, float[]> list = new HashMap<>();
    JSONArray array = new JSONArray(json);
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
        String dataByDevice = array.getString(i);
        String[] values = dataByDevice.split(":");
        /* first value is a key */
        Integer id = Integer.parseInt(values[0]);
        list.put(id, new float[values.length - 1]);
        /* others are values */
        for (int j = 1; j < values.length - 1; j++) {
            list.get(id)[j] = Float.parseFloat(values[j]);
        }
    }
    return list;
}

public void setValuesFromResponse(String response) {
    Map<Integer, float[]> parsedData = parse(response);

    for(Entry<Integer, float[]> entry : parsedData.entrySet()) {
        int parsedDeviceId = entry.getKey(); // get ID
        System.out.print(parsedDeviceId + " : ");
        for(float value : entry.getValue()) {
            System.out.print(value + ", ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

In all cases output for

```
String response = "[\"37:0.00\",\"60:23.50:55.00:22.22:52.00:192.55:20.00\",\"61:0.00\"]";
```

will be

```
37 : 0.0, 
60 : 23.5, 55.0, 22.22, 52.0, 192.55, 20.0, 
61 : 0.0,
```